# Explaining a pattern observed when computing $\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

While looking at various ways of computing $\binom{2n}{n}$ for various values of $n$, I tried the following method: First, define the sequence $T_0=\{n+1,...,2n\}$, then for $k=1,...,n$, given $T_{k-1}=\{a
^{(k-1)}_1,...,a^{(k-1)}_n\}$, define:
$$
t_{0}:=k , \\\,\\
t_{i}:=\frac{t_{i-1}}{\gcd\left(t_{i-1},\,a_i^{(k-1)}\right)}, \\ \,\\
a_{i}^{(k)}:=\frac{a_i^{(k-1)}}{\gcd\left(t_{i-1},\,a_i^{(k-1)}\right)}
$$ for $i=1,...,n$. Eventually, we get $\binom{2n}{n}=a_1^{(n)}\cdots a_n^{(n)}$.
By indicating for each $k=1,...,n$ which indices are affected by it (i.e. those $i$ for which $a_i^{(k-1)}\neq a_i^{(k)}$), we get a patterns like the following:

($n=10$)[image: Pattern for n=10]
The graph of the case $n=10$ is gotten as follows. 
In this case we have:
$$
T_0=\{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\} \\
T_1=\{11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\} \\
T_2=\{11,6,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\} \\
T_3=\{11,2,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20\} \\
T_4=\{11,1,13,7,15,16,17,18,19,20\} \\
\cdots
$$
So the first column won't have any points, because the first factor $11$ never changes. The second and third column would have a point at height $2$, because the second number changes $12\to6\to2$ while we cancel $2$ and $3$ respectively. The fourth column would have 2 points at height $2$ and $4$, because while cancelling the factor $4$ the second entry $2\to1$ and the fourth entry $14\to7$ etc..

($n=100$)[image: Pattern for n=100]
($n=1000$)[image: Pattern for n=1000]
($n=10000$)[image: Pattern for n=10000]
($n=40000$)[image: Pattern for n=40000]
Interestingly, by removing the entries for prime $k$'s from the graph we get the following image:
($n=40000$)[image: Pattern for n=40000 without primes]

Furthermore by coloring $k$'s of the form $p$, $2p$ and $3p$ in blue, green and cyan respectively, where $p$ is a prime, we get the following plot:

($n=40000$)[image: Pattern for n=40000 with primes colored]

Here's the same image without the red $k$'s:

($n=40000$)[image: Pattern for n=40000 with primes only]

And here's with additionally $4p$, $5p$ and $6p$ as magenta, yellow and black, respectively:

($n=40000$)[image]

Are there any known numerical properties of that can explain the above pattern?

---

Comment: I'm not sure if your notation is standard, but it's extremely confusing to me. In particular you seem to be reusing $k$, both as an index and as a variable name (maybe even as two variable names?).

Comment: @MeesdeVries
I've changed some of my notation. Hopefully this makes it clearer.

Comment: Is the graph showing the number of affected indices?

Comment: Can you give an example of this computation? Maybe for $n=3$ or $4$?

Comment: @automaticallyGenerated Added an example for $n=10$.

Comment: The plot looks like a bunch of [Euclid Orchards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_orchard) or [Thomae functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function) glued to a diagonal

Comment: Exactly what points are shown in the plot? This is still unclear to me. Can you show the pattern for a number that we can verify by hand in under two minutes? Like $n=7$ or something?

Comment: The idea seems to be to calculate 
$$\frac{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots(2n)}{1\cdot2\cdot3\cdots n}$$
in such a way that you divide the numerator by one factor of the denominator at a time, and in such a way that you do as much cancellation as possible as early as possible, processing whatever factors remain in the numerator in sequence. BUT FER PETE'S SAKE WHAT IS THE PROCESS OF TURNING THIS CALCULATION INTO A PLOT?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen That's exactly right. The plot represents the numbers among $n+1,...,2n$ (more preceisely, their indices) which are affected during each iteration of the cancellation (i.e. per item in the denominator).

Comment: So the $y$-axes is the index of the affected factor(s) of the numerator, and the $x$-axes is the factor from the denominator that is getting cancelled?

Comment: That is correct

Comment: I moved an edited version of the explanation for $n=10$ adjacent to the plot. I think that helps readers.

Comment: I think I can explain the rightmost "dotted line" with slope $m=2$. That "line" contains a dot (at least) for each prime number $p$ in the range $(n/2,n]$. In the cancellation process that factor $p$ will always be cancelled by the factor $2p$ in the numerator. This is because among the integers $n+1,n+2,\ldots,2n$, $2p$ is the smallest one that is divisible by $p$. The index of $2p$ in the numerator is $2p-n$. So to each such prime $p$, we have a dot at the point $(p,2p-n)$ in the plot. Those all fall on the line of slope $2$ through the point $(n,n)$.

Comment: (cont'd) There may also be other points on that line, but the primes are "dense enough" to have this kind of a visual impact.

Comment: But that argument does not explain, why that slope two line marks the right border of the plot (if it is?). It only explains why that line is heavily occupied.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I've added a plot where the prime $k$'s are removed.

Comment: Interesting! ${}$

Comment: The reason you see nothing in the upper left half is because the serie is locked in that case, the reason you barely see scattered clusters of affected elements in the other half is because the first major set of this serie became annihilated (nearly all $a_i=1$) , and what you see in blue color has strong relation with prime gaps. I will figure how to phrase this with mathematical terms.